# How to remove text AFTER | character in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

i have a list look like this

```
shpah:12341234 |09100500001

sohe1234:sohei1234 |09013053982
```

combo list with phone number how can i xchange in notepad++ to this

```
shpah:12341234

sohe1234:sohei1234
```

Comment: [RegEx](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace by using [Regular Expressions](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)

**Find what:**

```
\s*\|.*$
```

**Replace with:**
(nothing)

**Search mode:** Regular Expression

A test for the regex pattern [here](https://regex101.com/r/lbATnA/1/)